# Unable to draw a Rectangle2D and a Path2D on same JPanel, possible overlapping?

Tags: java, swing, awt, graphics2d

Ok this is probably a silly question and maybe I am missing something.  I am not new to Java but I am hardly an expert.  Long story short, I wrote a air compressed rocket trajectory simulation (no it wasn't homework).  It was my "hey I want to learn Java so let me try this" program.  It graphically simulates distance, max height, etc.  Now I am trying to add a second panel (JFrame) to show rocket stability in fight.

I have a JPanel within a JFrame.  Within that I have DrawPanel class that does the drawing.  I am trying to draw a rocket.  So I need a rectangular body, fins, nose cone, etc.  Now I have written a method for drawing the body using a Rectangle2D object, and a method for drawing 2 fins using a Path2D object.  Now when I have both in my paint method, it only draws whichever is first.  I have flipped them and it will only draw whatever is first.  Now is there something with graphics2D objects that they have whitespace take up the whole panel, or am I completely missing something.

I wrote a test program in the same design pattern as my main program in order to better try to fix this without launching the main.  Its a little longer than what you guys usually want but in case the issue isnt in the DrawPanel class I will include it and it does compile and run.  Also, I am sure that I am not doing this the most efficient way, so any tips or pointers are welcome too.  Thanks guys

```
/*
* Test program to replicate issue with main program
* Trying to draw multiple shapes, one ends up overlapping the other
*/
package shapetest;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ShapeTest extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    DrawPanel drawPanel = new DrawPanel();
    Rectangle2D rocket = new Rectangle2D.Double();
    Path2D.Double topFin = new Path2D.Double();
    Path2D.Double bottomFin = new Path2D.Double();

    int scaler = 20;
    double rocketX = 0;
    double rocketY = 0;

    class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        double rocketLength = 36;
        double rocketWidth = 1.5;

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            paint2D(g2);

            g2.dispose();
        }

        protected void paint2D(Graphics2D g2) {

            setBackground(Color.WHITE); // Set graph background color
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1.0f));
            g2.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 18));
            //If I reverse the order of these two methods, it will draw
            //the rocket tube and not the fin
            drawTwoFins(g2);
            drawRocketTube(g2, rocketLength, rocketWidth);
        }

        private void drawRocketTube(Graphics2D g, double rL, double rW) {            
            double rocketL = rL * scaler;
            double rocketW = rW * scaler;
            rocketX = ((drawPanel.getWidth() / 2) - ((rocketLength * scaler) / 2));
            rocketY = ((drawPanel.getHeight() / 2) - ((rocketWidth * scaler) / 2));

            rocket.setRect(rocketX, rocketY, rocketL, rocketW);
            g.draw(rocket);

            g.dispose();
        }

        private void drawTwoFins(Graphics2D g) {
            BasicStroke stroke = new BasicStroke(2.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL);
            g.setStroke(stroke);

            rocketX = ((drawPanel.getWidth() / 2) - ((rocketLength * scaler) / 2));
            rocketY = ((drawPanel.getHeight() / 2) - ((rocketWidth * scaler) / 2));

            double topStartX = (rocketX + (4 * scaler));
            double topStartY = rocketY;
            double bottomStartX = (rocketX + (4 * scaler));
            double bottomStartY = (rocketY + (rocketWidth * scaler));

            double xTopFin[] = {topStartX, (topStartX - (2 * scaler)), (topStartX - (5 * scaler)), (topStartX - (3 * scaler))};
            double yTopFin[] = {topStartY, (topStartY - (2 * scaler)), (topStartY - (2 * scaler)), topStartY};
            double xBottomFin[] = {bottomStartX, (bottomStartX - (2 * scaler)), (bottomStartX - (5 * scaler)), 
                               (bottomStartX - (3 * scaler))};
            double yBottomFin[] = {bottomStartY, (bottomStartY + (2 * scaler)), (bottomStartY + (2 * scaler)), bottomStartY};

            topFin.moveTo(xTopFin[0], yTopFin[0]);
            bottomFin.moveTo(xBottomFin[0], yBottomFin[0]);

            for (int i = 1; i < xTopFin.length; i++) {
                topFin.lineTo(xTopFin[i], yTopFin[i]);
                bottomFin.lineTo(xBottomFin[i], yBottomFin[i]);
            }

            g.draw(topFin);
            g.draw(bottomFin);
            g.dispose();
        }    
    }    

    private void initComponents() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(panel);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(850, 300));
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(drawPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public ShapeTest() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ShapeTest().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your drawing methods end with `g.dispose()`, but when you do this, the next drawing method is completely out of luck since you've effectively *obliterated* the Graphics object, and so they have nothing to draw with.

Solution: Don't keep disposing your Graphics object.

Some general rules

- Never dispose a Graphics object given to you by the JVM.
- Do dispose of Graphics objects that **you** create when done using them, but only when completely done. You're disposing them at the end of each method, completely wiping it out for the next method. Here you should only call dispose once, on g2 and at the end of the paintComponent method.
- You should dispose of the created g2 variable **once** at the end of the `paintComponent` method.

For that matter, I"m not sure that you need to make a copy of the Graphics object, and if you don't copy it via the create() method, then you should not dispose of it at all.

Comment: thank you for your assistance, that worked perfectly.  I am still getting used to not only java, but graphics and painting.  I really appreciate you taking the time to help me.  Do you have any suggestions as far as more efficient ways or more "correct" ways to do what I am trying to?

Comment: @MichaelMorgan: draw static images to a BufferedImage, and then display that BufferedImage in your paintComponent via `g.drawImage(...)`. Then after that, draw your dynamic images, such as moving sprites.